# TableView to PDF (Several Pages)

Tags: python, pyqt

I am hitting a major road block trying to export a complete tableview from my PyQt app to a pdf.

I've been able to some sort of pdf exports, but they always come out trimmed by the current 
viewing area.

I am looking for an example to export the complete tableview even if only some is visible at the moment of export.

I have some thumbnails in this tableview, so I guess it would be something that captures the visible images.

This is the code I have sofar, which manages to export a pdf with a portion of the tableview. Any hints would be appreciated!

```
def _print(self,  checked = None):
    if checked == None: return
    fileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', '', 'PDF Files (*.pdf)')
    if fileName == '': return

    #set up the QPrinter
    p = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    p.setPaperSize(QtGui.QPrinter.A4)
    p.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    p.setOrientation(QtGui.QPrinter.Landscape)
    p.setOutputFileName(fileName)

    #set up the painter
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    #Activate the painter to paint on p then give visual conformation that it worked or not.
    #If didn't work return out of method.
    if painter.begin(p) == False:
        msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText('An Error occoured while creating PDF')
        msgBox.setInformativeText('Could not save PDF')
        msgBox.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Critical)
        msgBox.exec_()
        return
    #self.ShotTableView.scale(200, 200);
    #painter.begin(printer)
    print self.ShotTableView.width()
    xscale = (self.ShotTableView.width() / 50);
    yscale = (self.ShotTableView.height() / 50);
    #scale = qMin(xscale, yscale);

    painter.scale(xscale, yscale);
    self.ShotTableView.render(painter)
    painter.end()
```

Comment: Hi Jacobs, I've added the code I have so far on my first port. Thanks!

Comment: @user1028826 what did you end up doing?