# How to save a treeview as pdf in PySide/PyQt?

Tags: qt, pdf, pyqt, pyside

**Short version**

I have a simple `QTreeView` embedded in a widget:

[image: the gui]

I want to save the tree as a PDF so users can print it. How can I do this?

**Details**

I want to save the tree as a PDF when I click the 'print' button. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735089/tableview-to-pdf-several-pages), and somewhat on [Qt documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF), I have tried doing it with the following method (see full SSCCE below for context):

```
def print_(self): 
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.Letter)
    printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName("treeTest.pdf")
    painter = QtGui.QPainter()
    painter.begin(printer)
    self.view.render(painter)
    painter.end()
```

But when this method is run, I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget.render' called with wrong argument types.  
PySide.QtGui.QWidget.render(PySide.QtGui.QPainter)
```

Curiously, [the documentation for render](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.render) has the first argument as a `QPainter` type, so I am not sure why my code isn't working, and especially am confused about the type error.

Am I missing some simple two-liner that will let me export my tree as a PDF?

**SSCCE**

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyTreeView(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.createModel()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        buttonLayout = self.buttonSetup()
        self.makeConnections()
        mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.view.expandAll()

    def createModel(self):
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Task', 'Comment'])
        self.rootItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        #First top-level row and children 
        item0 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Coding fun'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Make millions')]
        item00 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Write example'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Keep it simple')]
        item01 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('Post to SO'), QtGui.QStandardItem('Put on flame-retardant vest')]
        item00[0].setCheckable(True)
        item00[0].setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        item01[0].setCheckable(True)
        item01[0].setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.rootItem.appendRow(item0)
        item0[0].appendRow(item00)
        item0[0].appendRow(item01)

    def makeConnections(self):
        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.print_)
        self.quitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def print_(self):
        printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setPageSize(QtGui.QPrinter.Letter)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QtGui.QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName("treeTest.pdf")
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        self.view.render(painter)
        painter.end()

    def buttonSetup(self):
        self.printButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Print")
        self.quitButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        #Lay them out
        buttonLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.printButton)
        buttonLayout.addStretch()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.quitButton)
        return buttonLayout


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newTree = MyTreeView()
    newTree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.render), the variant of `QWidget.render` that has a `QPainter` as its first parameter expects a mandatory `targetOffset` of type `QPoint` as its second parameter. If I add an empty point it works for me (although the tree widget is printed very small).

```
painter.begin(printer)
try:
    self.view.render(painter, QtCore.QPoint())
finally:
    painter.end()
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in PySide. The [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render-2) and [PyQt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#render-2) both specify the `targetOffset` parameter as optional. Could be worth reporting it on the PySide bug tracker I guess...